# (NodeJS + Postman + MongoDB) Pagination problem

Tags: node.js, express

i have been doing pagination, but i can't get and see the second page info. the info isn't changing. it's keeping the first 4 info for all pages.
here is my code:

```
//routes
app.get("/bookstore", (req, res) => {

  const { page = 1, limit = 4 } = req.query;

  let mybook = [];
  // the collection name from mongoDB
  db.collection("bookstore")
    .find()
    .sort({ author: 1 })
    .limit(limit * 1)
    .skip((page - 1) * limit)
    .forEach((book) => mybook.push(book))
    .then(() => {
      return res.json(mybook);
    })
    .catch(() => {
      return res.send("there were an error");
    });
  // res.json({ MyWords: "I am coming from json res" });
});
```

i want to see other pages info

Comment: you can check this link https://github.com/ashwanibakshi/pagination/blob/master/app.js

Answer (score 0):

You're using `forEach()` method to push an array, for returning the array `mybook` `forEach()` method not support the promise `then()`, so for the replace of `forEach()` method you can use the `toArray()` method which will return the `mybook` array.

```
let mybook = [];
  db.collection("bookstore")
    .find()
    .sort({ author: 1 })
    .limit(limit * 1)
    .skip((page - 1) * limit)
    .toArray()
    .then((books) => {
      mybook = books;
      return res.json(mybook);
    })
    .catch(() => {
      return res.send("there was an error");
    });
```

Comment: it didn't work! it's still the same

Comment: refer this may helps- https://javascript.plainenglish.io/simple-pagination-with-node-js-mongoose-and-express-4942af479ab2

Comment: hi mate, no it didn't work. It showed the same mistake